# Setting header property in Mule Flow

Tags: mule

In my mule flow I am changing the payload using XSLT.
I need to set new header parameter which is expected by the service I am calling.

I tried using 
    set-property tag and also using message-properties-transformer tag but still having issues.

Whats the best way to set outbound header property ?

Comment: Post your config file here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set-property` is the best way to set outbound header property.

What issue did you have? Also what Mule version and maybe show the failing configuration.

Comment: It was the custom code that was the issue and not set-property. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately `<message-properties-transformer/>` with `scope="outbound"` is also a good option to set the outbound properties